# Condition to display text next to total amount in Gravity forms

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to display a text next to the total amount using gravity forms depending on the final amount. So how do I get to show for instance 'this text' into the code if amount is over 600?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){

 if(total > 600)
 document.body.innerText = 'this text';

return total;

} );

</script>
```

Above formula seems to work except for the part of the text, which redirects me automatically to a blank page with the text showing on top. I need that the text shows next or below the total div.
Anyone know how to get it? Thank you.

Comment: you have to post your HTML too

Comment: html from the total div?

Comment: <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_total">
      <span class="ginput_total ginput_total_18">1.332,45 €</span>
      <input type="hidden" name="input_51" id="input_18_51" class="gform_hidden" value="1332.45">
     </div>

Comment: ok then do document.querySelector('.ginput_container ginput_container_total').innerText += ' this text'; instead of document.body.innerText = 'this text';

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but no text is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Give a custom CSS class to that product field in gravity form admin page. 
https://docs.gravityforms.com/product/#appearance

If you give a class as 'product-field', the field html will be generated as

```
<div class="product-field ginput_container ginput_container_total"> 
<span class="ginput_total ginput_total_18">1.332,45 €</span> 
<input type="hidden" name="input_51" id="input_18_51" class="gform_hidden" value="1332.45"> 
</div>
```

Then you should get the field by its class. Append the html to the field div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){
 if(total > 600) {
  $('.product-field').append('<div>this text</div>');
 }
 return total;
});

</script>
```

Comment: so I added a class to the total field, but still it doesn't append the text... I want to show the total, and next to it the text

Comment: Please check if the class is added in the field html. If it is added, please check in console that you are getting DOM element for $('.product-field')

Comment: it is added in the <li>: <li id="field_18_51" class="gfield product-field gfield_price gfield_price_18_ gfield_total gfield_total_18_ field_sublabel_above field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_18_51">Total</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_total">
      <span class="ginput_total ginput_total_18">1.800,00 €</span>
      <input type="hidden" name="input_51" id="input_18_51" class="gform_hidden" value="1800">
     </div></li>

Comment: I tried using all possible classes but none seems to be displaying the text. Isn't there any other way to display text like showing a field? So when condition is that total amount is over 600 then a text shows, otherwise text is hidden, or not showing, whatever.

Comment: In the above html, which class you added?